# Are there disadvantages of using __slots__?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, memory-management

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I was reading about [`__slots__`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html) .  Evidently, `__slots__` can be used to optimize memory allocation for a large number of those objects by listing all the object properties ahead of time.

```py
class MyClass(object):
    __slots__ = ['name', 'identifier']
    def __init__(self, name, identifier):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.set_up()
```

My perhaps obvious question is why wouldn't we want to do this for all objects?  Are there disadvantages for using `__slots__`?

Comment: *Subjective (or context based) disadvantage:* dynamic attribute assignment doesn't work anymore as there is no `__dict__`.

Comment: how is this not a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/1358308 .  lots and lots of very useful information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fluent Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do) by *Luciano Ramalho* lists the following caveats

> • You must remember to redeclare `__slots__` in each subclass, since the
>   inherited attribute is ignored by the interpreter.
>
> • Instances will
>   only be able to have the attributes listed in `__slots__`, unless you
>   include `__dict__` in `__slots__` — but doing so may negate the memory
>   savings.
>
> • Instances cannot be targets of weak references unless you
>   remember to include `__weakref__` in `__slots__`.

Comment: I'm a novice to Python so I may be grossly oversimplifying your answer, but from what I'm reading, it appears the only disadvantages are you have to add more code into your model.  Am I reading you right?

Comment: Well, yes, grossly oversimplified. More code in subclasses (because `__slots__` from parent class are ignored) and dynamic attributes won't work (unless you do what's described in the second bullet point, which is kind of against what slots are for).

Comment: @Dušan Maďar I don't understand your first point. I have just been experimenting (Python 3.7.3) and inheritance seems to work as I would expect it to. That is, an instance of a class without \_\_slots\_\_ but derived from a class with \_\_slots\_\_ will have a \_\_dict\_\_ so new members can be added dynamically but assigning to a variable declared in the parent class's \_\_slots\_\_ will not and an entry to the object's \_\_dict\_\_.

Comment: @Dušan Maďar Your second point may qualify as a caveat but I would not call it a disadvantage. I think that this is how a class _should_ behave. If you need to add arbitrary attributes to individual  instances then you should not be using a class. Apart from the memory saved by not creating a dictionary for each object this gives a useful check for typing errors.

Comment: @ChrisBarry none of those points are mine. They are cited form `Fluent Python` (book). Please read the `first line` of the answer.

Comment: @Dušan Maďar I apologise for conflating citation with endorsement. I assumed that as you were prepared to cite them you would be willing to defend them. I think that, except for exotic cases (how often do you use weak references?) every class declaration should be followed by \_\_slots\_\_. Its non-ubiquity, at least in the Python code I have looked at, suggests that I am wrong. I am still wondering why.

Comment: "You must remember to redeclare `__slots__` in each subclass" is misleading. You should never redeclare any slots already declared by a superclass - doing so is undefined behavior, and in the current implementation, it causes instances to waste a bunch of extra memory. What you should do is declare any *new* slots introduced by a subclass, or set `__slots__ = ()` if there are no new slots.

Comment: (See the [notes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots) in the Python docs.)