# Why __slots__ isn't the default in Python?

Tags: python, attributes, python-internals

I've been programming in Python for a long time, but I still can't understand why classes base their attribute lookup on the `__dict__` dictionary by default instead of the faster `__slots__` tuple.

Wouldn't it make more sense to use the more efficient and less flexible `__slots__` method as the default implementation and instead make the more flexible, but slower `__dict__` method optional?

Also, if a class uses `__slots__` to store its attributes, there's no chance of mistakenly creating new attributes like this:

```py
class Object:
    __slots__ = ("name",)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

obj = Object()
# Note the typo here
obj.namr = "Karen"
```

So, I was wondering if there's a valid reason why Python defaults to accessing instance attributes through `__dict__` instead of through `__slots__`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there disadvantages of using \_\_slots\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767040/are-there-disadvantages-of-using-slots)

Comment: Just historically speaking, `__slots__` was an optimization added *later*. Perhaps this might have made sense to do from the beginning - it seems to be a matter of opinion to me - but in any case, that is simply not how the language was designed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is designed to be an extremely flexible language, and allows objects to modify themselves in many interesting ways at runtime. Making a change to prevent that kind of flexibility would break a massive amount of other people's code, so for the sake of backwards compatibility I don't think it will happen any time soon (if at all).

As well as this, due to the way Python code is interpreted, it is very difficult to design a system that can look ahead and determine exactly what variables a particular class will use ahead of time, especially given the existence of `setattr()` and other similar functions, which can modify the state of other objects in unpredictable ways.

In summary, Python is designed to value flexibility over performance, and as such, having `__slots__` be an optional technique to speed up parts of your code is a trade-off that you choose to make if you wish to write your code in Python. I can't answer whether this is a worthwhile design decision for you, since it's entirely based on opinion.

If you wish to have a bit more safety to prevent issues such as the one you described, there are tools such as `mypy` and `pylint` which can catch that sort of error.